# Epub extensions

Tags: release-juno

I have just transferred my E books that I used in Apple OS so they are in epub format.  What programme will open these?  I am unable to find a free one.  And definitely not in the repository?  I'm still learning

Answer (score 1):

You may give [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) a try. It's a free, open-source and cross-platform ebook manager/converter/reader, which supports .epub among other popular formats.

BTW, if you're unable to find calibre in your AppCenter or add its repository to your system, this probably means you have to execute `sudo apt install software-properties-common` command, which will allow to install apps from other (non-system) repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The App I am using is [Foliate](https://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/). Is does **not** come with Elementary, but is relatively easy to install, as the author supplies a [flatpak](https://flatpak.org)

To enable flatpaks on Elementary, follow the [elementary OS Quick Setup](https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS/):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common --no-install-recommends
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Next add  the flathub repository:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Last, install [foliate](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate) (this can be done as a regular user):

```
flatpak install foliate
```

**Note:** this is not the recommended way of installing software on Elementary, but it is [the way of the future](https://medium.com/elementaryos/elementary-appcenter-flatpak-b1f970a33861), and will hopefully be fully supported in 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a really good epub reader is a problem. I have loads of epub documents and I read them on 3 different platforms (Elementary/U18, SailfishOS & ReMarkable) and all three have apps which render the epub docs differently. If it is just text then all is fine, but throw in diagrams, illustrations, different chapter styles etc and things go awry.

Currently on Elementary, I have installed [Bookworm](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm) and [FBReader](https://fbreader.org/content/fbreader-beta-linux-desktop); FBReader is the epub app for SailfishOS as well. I have, at times, had Calibre installed but it is so big and, in my opinion, ungainly, that I have removed it.

I like Bookworm the most - it is the most elegant solution so far - but it is not the best for rendering. As I'm currently proofing a book for one of the better tech publishers, I make sure that if I read it in Bookworm, I also check it out either in pdf form or on a different device!

Comment: Tried Bookworm, which btw is distributed under 'pay what you want' model, and was disappointed immediately: the app can't correctly operate in two-page mode. The second page doesn't start where the first page ends, but from some seemingly random passage :(

Comment: @a-tokarev made coments about the two-page mode and the start of follow-on pages in Bookworm - this is exactly right and why I said it's not the best for rendering. If you have a simple doc it works fine and looks (and works) great but it falls over with anything complicated. So if you are reading that Dickens novel give it a go but if you are studying for that biology Phd then forget it as such textbooks will just annoy you in Bookworm.